# Looping through XML nodes using JavaScript and outputting a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm creating a webpage using JavaScript to create a table that has a separate row for each node that is in an XML file (note: I can't modify the XML file using XSL/XSLT for various reasons).

```
    <script>
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Books.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    document.write("<table id=name border='1'>");
    document.write("<tr><th>Book Name</th><th>Book Price</th><th>Book Author</th><th>Book Comments</th></tr>");  document.write("<tr>");
```

My problem is that the XML file has a different set of childNodes depending on the content available for any particular book, for example -

```
    <Book>
    <BookName>Cooking Today</BookName>
    <BookPrice>$6.99</BookPrice>
    </Book>

    <Book>
    <BookName>How To Make It</BookName>
    <BookPrice>$7.99</BookPrice>
    <BookAuthor>Gary Shaw</BookAuthor>
    <BookComments>OMG, it changed my life</BookComments>
    </Book>
```

The table I've created has all of the column names necessary for each field however because there are different childNodes for each book, the placement of these values in each row doesn't match up to the appropriate column.

Is there a way to have this script enter a blank/empty/null value when a specific field isn't available (ie. in the example above, I'd want a blank space in my table for the book, 'Cooking Today' for the missing fields - Book Author, Book Comments) ?

Answer (score 0):

## The first step: define an object scope

If you know every single node then you can define all variables of an object, right? Then do this before trying to do the XML reader. I suggest:

```
function Book() {
    this.importableVariables = ['bookName', 'bookPrice', 'bookAuthor', 'bookComments'];
}
Book.prototype.toRow = function() {
    var output = '<tr>';
    for (var x in this.importableVariables) {
        var vName = this.importableVariables[x];
        output += '<td>' + this[vName] + '</td>';
    }
    output += '</tr>';
    return output;

}
```

So now you have something that magically give to you a HTML Table Row. For example:

```
var book = new Book();
yourTableBodyJqueryRefference.append(book.toRow());
```

## The second step: do your XML Reader

That's not a very big deal. You can learn better [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp). I'll do just examples.
In my case, I want to split this step in more two steps.

## Step 2.1: importing a single line

Here I don't care what I'm reading in the string. I'll look for the variables listed at the Book constructor on `importableVariables`. So, if it exists, we should import that value to our object.

```
Book.prototype.instanceFromXML = function(str) {
    var parser, doc;
    if(window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml");
    } else {
        doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        doc.async = false;
        doc.loadXML(str);
    }
    for (var x in this.importableVariables) {
        var vName = this.importableVariables[x];
        var value = doc.getElementsByTagName(vName);
        this[vName] = value.length > 0 ? value[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue : '';
    }
}
```

## Step 2.2: full import

Now we will make the final magic. A function to read the entire XML and split into N Book instances.

```
function readXML(str) {
    var parser, doc;
    if(window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml");
    } else {
        doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        doc.async = false;
        doc.loadXML(str);
    }
    var xmlBooks = doc.getElementsByTagName("Book"), books = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < xmlBooks.length; i++) {
        var book = new Book();
        book.instanceFromXML(xmlBooks[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        books += book.toRow();
    }
    return books;
}
```

And the final call:

```
yourTableBodyJqueryRefference.append(readXML(yourXmlString));
```

Comment: I finally had a chance to try this out although don't have it working just yet, I'm assuming the XML file would go into the final call as in the following -       yourTableBodyJqueryRefference.append(readXML(Books.xml));

Comment: any idea if this would also work with void elements ? I also have a couple tags such as the following in this XML file that I'm reading, '</BookType>' (it's the equivalent of <BookType> </BookType> in normal HTML but in XHTML this seems to be common)

Comment: @shetaan819 can I see that?

Comment: @shetaan819 would be better if we could take a look to an example file (the entire thing), so I would be able to solve your problem, hehe